# Edit generated HTML before sent to client in MVC4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm wondering if there is way to access/edit the generated HTML from MVC4 that is going to be sent back to the client just before it is sent.

My main reason for wanting to access it is to apply the following code, ie, remove all newlines.

```
string newOneLineHtml= Regex.Replace(oldUglyHtml, @"\t|\n|\r", "");
```

I'm very aware that this wont make the page render or be sent faster as it is already zipped when transfered.. 
What it will do is make me more happy with the html as it is usually just a mess of horrible indentation if you inspect it from a browser.

Comment: Just 5 secs of googling: http://aspalliance.com/71_Modifying_Page_Output

Comment: Have you thought about overriding the onresultexecuted to get at the content and modifying it?